# Cannot convert .csv into a dataframe error: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I am trying to learn panda and tensorflow in colab, but i am having issues importing and manipulating CSV.

When i try to use a .csv file as dataframe in colab i get an error

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['GHI training.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
df
```

Outputs

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-d3546ec3306f> in <module>()
      2 import io
      3 
----> 4 df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['GHI training.csv'][:200].decode('utf-8')))
      5 df

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

here is the notebook i am trying to work
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14oSPEy8e9FwpiGeFfUpY83UaWKewE_iX

Currently i get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

i wish to have this CSV as a dataframe

Comment: Hi! You should tell us what is `uploaded` and what contains.

Comment: it is a CSV containing name of cities and certain numerical features for each city. The first rown is the name of each feature. the first column is the name of the cities. the rest of the table is just numbers.

I made it on MS Excel and saved as csv utf-8.

Comment: So you can directly read the `uploaded` file with `pd.read_csv()` , why include `StringIO`

Comment: removing io still results in the same error.

When i print uploaded['GHI training.csv'], i can se the content, not in dataframe format. But when i try to set it as datafram with pandas i still get 'str' object is not callable. I added this to the notebook linked in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why,

but i used created a data_pathfile with the pathfile for the document and it worked

```
data_pathfile = '../content/GHI training.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded[data_pathfile].decode('utf-8')))
```